# Is there a way to perform "mvn clean install" on multiple separate modules, when all the modules have different parents which can't be altered?

Tags: maven, project, maven-reactor

There's project with different modules and dependencies and all of them are needed to be mvn clean installed one by one in a particular sequence.And they have different parents and that can't be changed. Now how can I automate this process with maven reactor.So just by performing "mvn clean install" just once will perform the same operation on all the modules in the given sequence .

Comment: Is this a multi module build?

Comment: well all I know is there are 20 modules which are expected to work only if they are clean installed in a given sequence.

Comment: If you have a parent pom which contains `<modules>..</modules>` and all module (childs) define a parent to the previously mentioned parent you should be able to build them in one go from the parent location with `mvn clean package`. There should no need for `mvn clean install`..you have to define the dependencies between the modules.

Comment: @khmarbaise that's the problem ... the children have org's repos as parent . there's no common parent pom.

Comment: But that's now called an aggregator which should work. Just call `mvn clean package` from the root module ?

Comment: @khmarbaise did what you said and got this error 

Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.ReactorModuleConvergence failed with message:
The reactor contains different versions.
The reactor is not valid

Comment: That's something different which means you have enforcer in your build..which either means you have to line up your versions in all your pom's but based on what you said that will not work which means your parent inherits/uses enforcer rules which are not valid in this circumstances..

Comment: @khmarbaise so what other options do I have ?

Comment: you have to either a different parent or change your pom depending on where the rules is configured. But this rules gives a hint that the versions in your multi module build should be same....furthermore having different parents in your multi module build makes usually no sense and the enforcer rules shows someone has thought about that?...

Comment: but I am not supposed to alter anything in the existing poms. I can only create a new pom and use the existing ones.
Anything that I can do ? 
and about versions, they all have different versions as they are being developed by separate teams.So Iam not sure about anything...any way that I can perform clean install without changing the parent of those poms ?

Comment: can you help me with the error I'm receiving in the maven reactor ? is there any workaround ?

Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.ReactorModuleConvergence failed with message:
The reactor contains different versions.
The reactor is not valid

Comment: @khmarbaise ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can Work with Multiple Modules  https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: can you elaborate more on that ?

Comment: actually I created a pom file with <modules> but it is showing reactor contains different versions error.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new parent of all other parents, this parent will be projects aggregator for all the other modules (the other parents), in that new parent you can order the modules as you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>build-all</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>../proj1/pom.xml </module>
        <module>../proj2/pom.xml </module>
        .
        .

    </modules>

</project>
```

Comment: those parents are repos of an org and I think that can't be done the way you proposed it to do.

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it using this idea

Comment: how can I create a parent pom of those repos which are not in my system at the begining ? I told you that the modules have some repos which are not the part of project, are the parent of those modules. And if I try the code in the screenshot, it gives  

Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.ReactorModuleConvergence failed with message:
The reactor contains different versions.
The reactor is not valid